# How to use {php} in smarty, for cmsms 1.11

Tags: php, smarty, cmsmadesimple

From April 2012 is for CMS Made Simple removed use_smarty_php_tags from config.php.
How can I use `{php} {/php}` tags in templates now?

I can not find any explanation how to insert php code into templation outside of user defined tags (they are good if I use it on multiple pages, but I need short php code only in one site).

[On this site (pdf file down)](http://docs.cmsmadesimple.org/configuration/config-file) there is a info about removing this parameter from configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UDT and include that in your page. See:
http://docs.cmsmadesimple.org/tags/user-defined-tags

Comment: Result is, that "outside of UDT" (what I asking for) it is impossible. OK, I wanted to avoid using UDT that is suitable for repetitive things, but I think it is no other solution.. now smarty has no direct alternative for {php} {/php} tags.